# How to store people who liked a post in Parse?

Tags: parse-platform, relationship

So I have a "Post" Class in Parse where I store the status written by my users on a social network app.

Now I want to know if the current logged-in user has already liked a status he sees in his feed. The issue is that I don't really know how to "design" this.

- I have a "Post" class, which stores all of the posts of the app.
- I have a "Like" class, which stores all of the likes given by a specific user (Pointer to the User Class) to a specific post (Pointer to the Post class).

Should I add an "Array" column to my "Post" class in which I would store all of the user IDs who liked a particular post ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new object for each like given.
So a 'Like' object should look like this:

```
user_id: 1
post_id: 40
```

Now an user can have multiple 'likes', so there are multiple like object for one user.
So if your all likes for user 1. You can create a query like:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Like")
query.whereKey("user_id", equalTo:"1")
```

Hope this will help you ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I already did. But I don't really know how to create a "join" with this class while I list the posts on the user's feed.

Comment: You can just find all the "Like" objects as I've shown above.
Then store the post_id's in an array and loop over it, where you want to use it.